# In a Python LinkedList, why use sentinel nodes instead of a None or Null

Tags: python, linked-list

What is the difference between these constructors for a LinkedList, why is one better or worse than the other?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Singly_Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
```

versus:

```
class Singly_Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(0)
```

Does this affect how the SLL or DLL would be implemented for the addAtIndex, removeAtIndex functions for example?

Comment: how do you know it's a sentinel node and not a regular node with value 0?

Comment: Note, python doesn't have `null`... but `None` would actually be fine and the natural way to do this, since you know that `next` will always be a `Node` or `None`, i.e. it is `Optional[Node]`. In many academic treatments, you define a special `Node` object that works as a sentinel, but `None` works in this case and would be pretty idiomatic. `Node(0)` would definitely be a bad choice, you would probably just want to do something  like `class EndNode(Node): pass` and then use `isinstance(node, EndNode)` and maybe a constructor that doesn't accept `data` if you really wanted a sentinel.